# Drupal module not showing up

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

So I'm NEW to drupal modules, actually this is my third module ever written...
The problem however is that it doesn't show up in the modules menu.
I have tried flushing the case multiple times.

The ini files looks the following:

```
name = Support Email
description = Provides a block to send support an email.

core = 7.x
```

I do have a .module file as well, which i have shaved to the bare minimum in order to avoid any errors:

```
<?php
  /**
   * Implements hook_block_info().
   * 
   * Declares a block to provide to Drupal. This can also specify block
   * configuration settings, like here where the cache is determined be the
   * user role.
   *
   * @url: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7
   */
  function support_email_block_info() {
    $blocks['support_email'] = array(
      'info' => t('aasup_faq2'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    );

    return $blocks;
  }<
```

Now, I have tried flushing the case multiple times with no success... The files are all placed the following folders:
sites/all/modules/custom/module_name
The two other modules works fine and never had a problem... They do share a lot of code, so it surprises me that this one does not work at all...

Comment: _The ini files looks the following_...Modules are defined with a `.info` file, not `.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with proper .info file it should list your module on admin module page. Hope your module folder name is **support_email**.
Also check last line of your .module page. `}<`

Comment: Well, yes, the folder has the same name ^^
The < sign is not atually there in the file, i must have accidentally added it during the copying process ^^

Comment: Waaait... that seems to be the issue, I looked at the wrong list... I was in the list of blocks not modules... It is indeed in the modules page and it's not enabled, thanks a lot!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can check the .info file whether it has been listed on admin module page. At the same time, check the last line of your .module page.